# Eager Loading return null in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have a issue with Eager Loading

I have two models :

```
class Provider extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the currency record associated with the provider.
     */
    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Currency', 'tabcur', 'poucur')->where('tabcol','$DEV');
    }
```

```
class Currency extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the providers record associated with the currency.
     */
    public function provider()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Provider', 'tabcur', 'poucur');
    }
```

When i try this :

```
Provider::first()->currency
```

It's works

But, if i try this :

```
Provider::with('currency')->first()
```

The field currency is null

```
currency: null,
```

Can anyone help me ?

**EDIT 1**

I tried this

```
>>> DB::connection()->enableQueryLog()

>>> App\Provider::with('currency')->first()

>>> DB::getQueryLog()
```

I have this with App\Provider::with('currency')->first()

```
   [
     [
       "query" => "select * from PROVIDER FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY",
       "bindings" => [],
       "time" => 18.74,
     ],
     [
       "query" => "select * from CURRENCY where tabcol = ?  and CURRENCY.tabcur in (?)",
       "bindings" => [
         "$DEV",
         "   ",
       ],
       "time" => 33.94,
     ],
   ]
```

But it's steel "null"

Comment: do you have a `currency` column in your Provider table? If yes, then change the relation name.

Comment: No, i dont have a "currency" column in my provider table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What **`first()`** do is:

> The `first` method returns the first element in the collection that passes a given truth test.

So when the Eager loading *test* is passed, It returns the  >>**First Record**<<  with the relation loaded.

### But

Your Relation `currency` is returning empty because the `where` condition in your currency relation is not passed so it will show that the the relation is loaded with `with` but it won't show any records because it didn't pass the `where`.

This happened because the first record that met the `with` condition did not pass the where condition, try to remove the `where` then load the relation again and see what is the value of `tabcol`, then do it again but this time with `where` but put the value you found for that returned record and it should work.

Comment: I remove `where` condition in my model, put the new value of tabcol and try it with the new value but the field currency still `null`

Answer (score 0):

`Provider::first()->currency` is gonna return a **Currency::class**

`Provider::with('currency')->first()` will return a **Provider::class** with Currency::class inside the **relations[]**

I don't see any reason why your code would not work.

Comment: The database it's encode in ISO-8859-15, it's maybe the problem ?